# Starting a sentence with "WHERE"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subject-verb-inversion, where

I wonder if it's grammatically or stylistically correct to start a sentence with "**Where**"

> e.g. Where the wardrobe is, there is no dust"

It sounds a bit weird to my ear but I don't know exactly why.

Comment: It doesn't sound wrong, so it is at least colloquially acceptable.

Comment: It's an example of [inversion](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/inversion) (from the idiomatically standard sequence *There is no dust where the wardrobe is*). You tend to meet it in poetic/literary contexts, and aphorisms/sayings. It's not at all common in normal conversation.

Comment: It is appropriate for a proverb or for a song,  e.g.  ["Where the boys are, someone waits for me"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Boys_Are_%28Connie_Francis_song%29). It would sound rather pompous in ordinary speech.

Comment: Where to place an interrogative adverb in a sentence is a matter of style, but remember: Where there's smoke, there's fire.

Comment: @deadrat And writing in good style can be difficult, but remember: where there's a will, there's a way.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: [*Where there's muck, there's brass.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Where+there%27s+muck+there%27s+brass%22) And so on and so forth. But all these examples are either well-established "frozen forms" themselves, or they're latter-day attempts to *emulate* such traditional sayings. This kind of inversion is hardly "colloquially acceptable" within the context of new dynamically-generated conversational utterances except when there's an element of "facetiously" playing with forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where you got such an absurd idea is beyond me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Facetious? Quite so, as in, O FumbleFingers, FumbleFingers! Where [-fore] for art thou FumbleFingers? (With apologies to the Bard)

Comment: Syntactically, it's called 'preposing' (not inversion). The adjunct "where the wardrobe is" would normally occur at the end of the sentence, but here it has been preposed to the beginning, presumably for some kind of stylistic effect (which eludes me). The basic order would of course be "There is no dust where the wardrobe is".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm afraid I don't understand the significance of the dummy *it* necessary to resequence the example. It's (and *it's*) not always required. Consider *Where you got the money is the question* -> *The question is where you got the money*.

Comment: (where the first of those is imho dated/poetic, but not the second.)

Answer (score 3):

In your specific example, it is fine. It sounds a little weird only because it is more common to say a sentence like this the other way around. (There is no dust where the wardrobe is.)

But if we always said things the most common way, books would be hella dull.

Comment: +1 for the little flourish at the end of your answer, made me chuckle

Answer (score 0):

> Where the wardrobe is, there is no dust.

What you wrote is called a Complex Sentence. It has one main (independent) clause and one subordinate (dependent) clause.

Main clause: there is no dust [As you can see, an independent clause can stand on its own as a sentence.]

Dependent: Where the wardrobe is

The dependent clause is an adverb dependent clause that acts like an adverb modifying the verb "is" in the main clause. It answers what an adverb may ask, "*Where*?" "Where is there no dust?" Where the wardrobe is. [There is, where the wardrobe is, no dust.]

All you did was move the clause to the beginning of the sentence, and when you do that you usually add a comma. If you place it in the usual position, the sentence becomes clearer:

There is no dust where the wardrobe is.

Used as a subordinating conjunction in your sentence, *where* means: *at, in, or to the place indicated* --Webster's.

In your sentence "the place indicated" is where the wardrobe is kept, maybe an air-tight closet, well sealed to keep out the dust and moisture.

EDIT:

"Where the vulture are, there lies the carcass."

Comment: Do you smell smoke? Where there's smoke, there's fire.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question ("*I wonder if it's grammatically or stylistically correct to start a sentence with "Where"*").

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way.